# Web3 TypeError when connecting to HTTPProvider

Tags: javascript, web3js

First of all, thank you very much in advance for your support. We are experiencing some issues with the compilation of a piece of code with `node.js`. In this sense, we are following the guideline in
[EthSigner](https://docs.ethsigner.consensys.net/Tutorials/Start-EthSigner) about the creation of the keystore key file. This means creating the following piece of script:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

// Web3 initialization (should point to the JSON-RPC endpoint)
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8540"));

var V3KeyStore = 
web3.eth.accounts.encrypt("key", "password");
console.log(JSON.stringify(V3KeyStore));
process.exit();
```

When compiling with `node`, then, the following exception is reached:

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8540"));
                 ^
TypeError: Web3.providers.HttpProvider is not a constructor
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rock/BESU/ETHSIGNER/account1/createAccount.js:4:23)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
   at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain](node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
   at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v20.2.0
```

I have seen within the docs of Web3 that HttpProvider is deprecated ([Web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3.html#providers)). But, we have not seen the way how to proceed instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the URI directly to the `Web3` constructor and omit the provider. Web3 will figure it out automatically.

`const web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8540");`